# Deleting field collection bundle programmatically from core

Tags: entities

I have a field collection bundle that I want to remove from my site. I was googling how to do that and  came upon [these instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1366198), but they seem to be from the [ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) module, and only apply to entities created by eck. The company I work for has a module review process and this module doesn't have a stable release yet.

So, ideally there would be a way for me to do this from core, or at least the field collection module, without extra modules. Is there?

*Edit* "No, you can't" is a perfectly acceptable answer. If that's the case I would like to stop chasing down blind alleys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently what I needed was [`field_delete_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_delete_field/7), and then a `field_purge_batch()`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try solution described in this blog post?
http://gix.my/blog/programmatically-creatingdeletingmodifying-field-collection-item-node

Comment: This only deleted instances of field collections, not the entire field collection itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that "*this module doesn't have a stable release yet*" is a slightly incorrect statement for the ECK module. It should rather be something like "*this module doesn't have an official release yet*".

Below are some qualifications that should help to proof that the 7.x-2.0-rc7 version of ECK is pretty stable:

- a version qualifier with [RC7](https://www.drupal.org/node/2414035) (already): that appears to me like not just the first attempt to create an RC-version.
- over [11.000 sites using this modules already](https://www.drupal.org/project/usage/eck), and with an impressive weekly increase of this number since already very long (ignore the downloads counter, that number is wrong for all projects these days, a known issue).
- Look at the remaining "open" issues in the [Roadmap for the 7.x-2.0 release](https://www.drupal.org/node/2382255): none.
- Already a [D8 version](https://www.drupal.org/node/2477367) in the pipeline.
- A healthy [commit log](https://www.drupal.org/node/1155832/commits) (last commits from only a few days ago).
- A healthy [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/eck?categories=All).
- A lot of [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1366144) available also.

If you're looking for even more of such qualifications, then you may want to check if there are any other applicable criteria as described in the "[Maintenance Scorecards](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#scorecards)" (which can also be applied to ECK).

For all these reasons, I think the "RC7" part of the version ID is rather a matter of "What's in a name". Consider using these types of arguments to try to get an exception to your company's policies (review process).

Comment: That's great, but am I wrong in my understanding that eck only can delete entity types created with eck?

Comment: I'm not sure (yet, need to do some more checking), but can you be more specific where you got that from, where you read that, what makes you think so, etc?

Comment: When I run a drush script with `$entity_types = EntityType::loadAll();`, `print_r($entity_types);` returns an empty array. These instructions https://www.drupal.org/node/1366198 say "After an entity type is loaded, deleting it is a simple call to the delete method.", but, since the array is empty, I seem not to have loaded any entities (I know I already have several on the site. 

But, if I follow the instructions on the page to create a new `eck_employee` entity, suddently the `loadAll()` array is has only one entity, the `eck_employee` entity. So it seems it can only hand its own entities.

Comment: Thx for that link. It has a phrase like "If you wanted to get all of the entity types created through ECK you can use loadAll()." ... Note the "through ECK" in it. But you have not used ECK to create entity types, right? Isn't that the explanation why you get an empty array? And because of that empty array, the delete doesn't work either. Maybe I am (still) missing something?

Comment: I haven't used ECK to build my field collection entities.

Comment: Indeed, that is my point also: THAT is why your drush script returns an empty array I think. And hence the delete doesn't work either.

Comment: Well yeah -- I am looking for how to delete my non-ECK created entities, which, in this case, happen to be field collections. While searching, I discovered this ECK manual page that talked about deleting entities, but wasn't explicitly clear that it only applied to ECK-created entities. So I still need something that can delete arbitrary entities. Sorry I wasn't clearer in my question :s

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/node/2384323

this patch will help you. it worked for me.

Comment: This looks like a patch for deleting individual field collections?

Comment: yes,,, that is.